# Прошу проконсультировать по JS-коду

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsp

Разбираюсь с чужим js-кодом, которым раньше не занимался. Есть строка на JSP-странице:

```
<body onclick="return{param1:'value', 'param2' : 'value2' ...}">
```

Нигде в литературе не нашел подобного примера. 
Есть подозрения, что при любом клике на странице отправляются параметры в JSON-формате, но что конкретно происходит - не ясно. Прошу объяснить.

Comment: Если вы привели полный код, то данный код сам по себе **ничего** не делает. Если у вас есть основания полагать, что он все же на что-то влияет - выкладывайте полный код.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. JSP-страница огромная - несколько тысяч строк. Сможете подсказать на что следует обратить внимание в данном случае? Т.е. с чем данная строка может быть связана, в каких случаях могут использовать такой синтаксис.

Comment: Обращайте внимания на то как данные получаются из JSP. И вопрос возникает *где* вы используете JSP в коде?

Comment: Отправляемые параметры (value1 и value2) вычисляются, но меня интересует не это. Интересует, что конкретно делает данная строка, а точнее что и куда отправляется по клику? и по какому клику. Спасибо.

Comment: Данная строка кода ничего никуда не отправляет. Вам надо смотреть другое место в вашем коде, откуда отправляется.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Что то эта запись означает... Можете какой нибудь пример кода привести (или несколько), который может быть связан с этой строкой?

Comment: Эта запись означает, что писал непонимающий, что делает в принципе.

Answer (score 0):

Вот подробное описание onclick: https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action
На самом деле, это событие не делает ничего, не понятно зачем оно там прописано